# Send events to Azure event hub using Python

Tags: python, azure, azure-eventhub

Below is the sample code copied from Microsoft's [site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send). I did replace the Event Hubs `<namespace>`, `<eventhub>`, `<AccessKeyName>`, and `<primary key value>` with the required values.

```
import sys
import logging
import datetime
import time
import os

from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData

logger = logging.getLogger("azure")

# Address can be in either of these formats:
# "amqps://<URL-encoded-SAS-policy>:<URL-encoded-SAS-key>@<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/eventhub"
# "amqps://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<eventhub>"
# SAS policy and key are not required if they are encoded in the URL

ADDRESS = "amqps://<namespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<eventhub>"
USER = "<AccessKeyName>"
KEY = "<primary key value>"

try:
    if not ADDRESS:
        raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

    # Create Event Hubs client
    client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, debug=False, username=USER, password=KEY)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="0")
    client.run()
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(100):
            print("Sending message: {}".format(i))
            message = "Message {}".format(i)
            sender.send(EventData(message))
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        client.stop()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info("Runtime: {} seconds".format(run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

However, when I execute this code, I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newBlobStream.py", line 7, in <module>
    from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData
ImportError: cannot import name 'EventHubClient' from 'azure.eventhub'
```

Comment: please add which pip package version you are using

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send) you followed is a legacy one. As of now, the new version of azure-eventhub for python is v5 and is installed by default(when using `pip install azure-eventhub`), please follow the code below to send events:

```
import asyncio
from azure.eventhub.aio import EventHubProducerClient
from azure.eventhub import EventData

async def run():
    # create a producer client to send messages to the event hub
    # specify connection string to your event hubs namespace and
        # the event hub name
    producer = EventHubProducerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str="EVENT HUBS NAMESPACE - CONNECTION STRING", eventhub_name="EVENT HUB NAME")
    async with producer:
        # create a batch
        event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()

        # add events to the batch
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('First event '))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('Second event'))
        event_data_batch.add(EventData('Third event'))

        # send the batch of events to the event hub
        await producer.send_batch(event_data_batch)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(run())
```

And for more details about `sending` / `receiving` events using the latest package, you can refer to this latest [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-python-send-v2).

Hope it helps.

Comment: can we publish data to specific consumer group ??

Comment: @Stark, no. Consumer group is just used to receive data. Data is published to Partitions. A consumer group will receive data from each Partition.

Comment: can you please explain little bit more "A consumer group will receive data from each Partition".

Comment: lets suppose I have created 2 consumer groups.. and minimum partition 1.. then how does it behave..

Comment: @Stark, if you have 2 consumer groups, then the 2 consumer group(each of them) will receive the same data from the partitions.

Comment: then what is advantage of the creating multiple consumer group when the same data is available in all the groups ??

Comment: @Stark, if there're multi users(consumers), you can give different consumer groups to different users, so all the users can fetch all the same data(if all the users are using a same consumer group, there is a competition, each user only fetch a part of the data). But that depends on your design.

Comment: Not sure I understand the `event_data_batch.add(EventData('First event'))`.
Is this to push in more events to the event hub if this `event_data_batch = await producer.create_batch()` is not able to push all events in, due to threshold limitations?

Answer (score 1):

pip install will pick new SDK which is 5.0 by default. The sample code won't runt with 5.0. Please install 1.3.1 of the Event Hubs SDK. It should work.