# Event hub Send failed MessageSendResult.Timeout Python

Tags: python, azure, networking, azure-eventhub

I have been having some issues with timeouts while sending messages to EventHub.

```
import sys
import logging
import datetime
import time
import os

from azure.eventhub import EventHubClient, Sender, EventData


logger = logging.getLogger("azure")
ADDRESS = "xxx"
USER = "xxx"
KEY = "xxx"
ENDPOINT = "xxx"

try:
    if not ADDRESS:
        raise ValueError("No EventHubs URL supplied.")

    # Create Event Hubs client
    client = EventHubClient(ADDRESS, username=USER, password=KEY, debug=True)
    sender = client.add_sender(partition="0", send_timeout=300, keep_alive=10)
    client.run()
    try:
        start_time = time.time()
        for i in range(10000):
            print("Sending message: {}".format(i))
            message = "Message {}".format(i)
            sender.send(EventData(message))
    except:
        raise
    finally:
        end_time = time.time()
        client.stop()
        run_time = end_time - start_time
        logger.info("Runtime: {} seconds".format(run_time))

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

My context is as follow;  i am able to send messages without problem from my personal development computer, from a virtual machine in Azure, and from on premises server1, but when trying to send messages to on premises server2 i receive the error:

```
azure.eventhub.common.EventHubError: Send failed:  Message send failed with result: MessageSendResult.Timeout
```

I have tried modifying the send_timeout and the keep_alive (even though i dont belive this configurations are to blame) but with no success, my personal guess is that there is something in my on premises server2 that is blocking or interfering with my communication. Firstly, am i changing the timeout value correctly? i have checked the source code of the class here: [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/eventhub_track1/sdk/eventhub/azure-eventhubs/azure/eventhub/sender.py)  but it seems i am doing it right, but i actually belive such property implies the time after the message is in the queue for sending instead of how long we wait for the response of the event. Secondly, is there a way i can validate that the problem relies on the envoiroment of my on premises server2? for example like exploring the network path with traceroute, or dig? The system is a CentOS. Could it be related to new upgrades in the Python SDK? i just saw this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59787512/send-events-to-azure-event-hub-using-python) where it shows that my method for uploading events has been upgraded just the "01/08/2020" maybe is something related to such upgrades(i doubt it)?

Anyhow, any clues would be greatly aprecciated. For now i will be testing on other servers and checking i can manage to change my implementation to the newer version and see if that solves the issue.

Comment: I have this same issue

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like a networking issue. Try pinging TCP endpoint of your namespace on port 9354 on server2. If firewall is blocking outbound connection to the endpoint, then either you need to fix it or try enabling websockets which can go through 443.